# Is there a way to batch resample and mosaic/merge many large raster files at once?

Tags: raster, dem, merge, mosaic, resampling

I have over 400 large raster DEM files at 1 m resolution that I need to resample to 10 m resolution and merge/mosaic them all into one file. I am wondering if there is a way to do this all in one step or as few steps as possible. I assume it would be faster to resample first, then mosaic.

The reason I need to resample is because the other data I am working with is 10 m resolution. I have looked into the problem online, but have not found anything helpful yet.

Does anyone know any tools that can to do this? And which program can do it best? I have ArcGIS and QGIS but may be able to get access to other programs if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Consider a mosaic dataset https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000003p000000 , you can try setting your target pixel size to 10m https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Set_Mosaic_Dataset_Properties/001700000161000000/ and then reference the 400+ rasters... theoretically it should resample on the fly from 1 to 10m then if you need a more traditional raster file you can export the mosaic dataset.